# 978.gs is cutting of part of the header

Tags: css, html

I am using the 978.gs system in a site that I am creating but it is inserting a small band at the top of the page moving the content down slightly. I don't want this to happen.

The site in question is [Located Here](http://www.cis.caspiantiger.com.au) look at the top of the page.

and my CSS code is

```
    /* Initiate 978.gs */
div.layout-978 { width: 978px; margin: 0px auto; }
div.row { height: 1%; }
div.row-end { clear: both; font: 1px/1px sans-serif; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; }
div.col1, div.col2, div.col3, div.col4, div.col5, div.col6, div.col7, div.col8, div.col9, div.col10, div.col11, div.col12 { float: left; margin-left: 30px; }
div.col1:first-child, div.col2:first-child, div.col3:first-child, div.col4:first-child, div.col5:first-child, div.col6:first-child, div.col7:first-child, div.col8:first-child, div.col9:first-child, div.col10:first-child, div.col11:first-child, div.col12:first-child { margin-left: 0px; }
div.col1 { width: 54px; }
div.col2 { width: 138px; }
div.col3 { width: 222px; }
div.col4 { width: 306px; }
div.col5 { width: 390px; }
div.col6 { width: 474px; }
div.col7 { width: 558px; }
div.col8 { width: 642px; }
div.col9 { width: 726px; }
div.col10 { width: 810px; }
div.col11 { width: 894px; }
div.col12 { width: 978px; }

/* Main CSS */
body{
    background: url('img/bg-texture.jpg');
    position:relative;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

To fix this problem I edited the following css entry

```
body{
background: url('img/bg-texture.jpg');
position:relative;
margin-top:0px;
}
```